# How to create multiple jQuery functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I was writing some code and noticed that jquery has a very cool feature

For example:

```
$(selector).addClass('').on('').on ('').remove();
```

I can do it 2.

```
func(...).func2('');
```

wanted to know how to do this (I guess I did not explain right).

This guy also has benchmarkjs it.
http://benchmarkjs.com/

**If someone could help me would be great! Thank you in advance**

Comment: Read on "fluent interfaces", "chaining" and possibly "prototypes"  in JavaScript. There is plenty of info online on these subjects.

Comment: What exactly is your question?  Any function or method that returns an object with methods itself can be chained like jQuery does.  The first function is called, it returns an object which you can call methods on with chaining and so on.  jQuery has a convention for most methods to return the original jQuery object which means you can call multiple methods on the same jQuery object with chaining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply return yourself in every function:

```
YourClass.prototype.a = function() {
    // do a stuff
    return this;
};
YourClass.prototype.a = function() {
    // do b stuff
    return this;
};

new YourClass().a().b();
```

[In the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20961265/how-to-create-multiple-jquery-functions/20961306?noredirect=1#comment31488732_20961306), you said:

> In jquery if I request html ( $().html() ) it returns the thread and still works

Well, that's easy as well:

```
YourClass.prototype.html = function(val) {
    if (val === undefined) {
        // return the html  
    } else {
        // set the html to val
        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it did not work, it appears that the second function does not exist

Comment: @IagoBruno Exactly what did you try? Could you post a fiddle?

Comment: Have you created the constructor?

Comment: ours worked. but I use the callback method to something else in all functions

Comment: @IagoBruno Ummm... what? I'm not sure what you're trying to say

Comment: in every function I return a value, so I can not use your way. In function of the text I retoro innerText the element. I function in html return the innerHTML of the element

Comment: @IagoBruno Well, if you return a value, how do you expect to access it?

Comment: That's what I wanted to know, wanted to know how to do it otherwise.

Comment: @Iago Don't use this chaining, and just use regular methods, then.

Comment: I tried it your way but appears: Object kkkkkkkkkkk has no method 'text'

Comment: In jquery if I request html ( $().html() ) it returns the thread and still works

Comment: @Iago That's because jQuery returns the element's HTML if the argument is undefined, otherwise it sets the HTML and returns the element.

Answer (score 1):

The key is always returning the object (read context) on every method. The simplest example:

```
var lib = {
  a: function() {
    //...
    return this;
  },
  b: function() {
    //...
    return this;
  }
};
```

And use it like:

```
lib.a().b();
```

But since this is such a common thing to do, an approach to fluent interface is a `fluent` decorator:

```
// A fluent function decorator:
// Takes a function and returns a function that returns `this`
var fluent = function(f) {
  return function() {
    f.apply(this, arguments);
    return this;
  };
};

var lib = {
  a: fluent(function() {
    //...
  }),
  b: fluent(function() {
    //...
  })
};

lib.a().b();
```

Another approach with `prototypes`, using the same helper:

```
function Lib() {} // constructor
Lib.prototype.a = fluent(function() {
  //...
});
Lib.prototype.b = fluent(function() {
  //...
});

new Lib().a().b();
```

The `fluent` decorator gives you the clue right away at the beginning of the function, rather than having to track down the returned value of the function.